# Obtaining a value from an attribute without quotation marks with lxml and XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, lxml

I'm working with XML docs that have structures similar to the following:

```
<root>

<tok lemma="A" xpos="AQ0MS00">sobredit</tok>
<tok lemma="B" xpos="Fc"> this </tok>
<tok lemma="something" xpos="AQ0MS00">something</tok>
<tok lemma="X" xpos="Fc"> that </tok>
<tok>del
  <dtok form="de" lemma="de" xpos="SPC00"/>
  <dtok form="el" lemma="el" xpos="DA0MS0"/>
</tok> 
<tok lemma="sobredit" xpos="AQ0MS00">sobredit </tok>
<tok lemma="X" xpos="Fc"> sometinelse </tok>

</root>
```

I use the following code (Python and LXML) to get the values of the attribute 'lemma' whenever a 'tok' element has value starting with 'AQ' for the attribute 'xpos'.

```
   for el in root_element.xpath('//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "AQ")]')
        
        if el.xpath('preceding::tok[1]/dtok'):

            prec_lem = el.xpath('preceding::tok[1]/dtok[last()]/@lemma')

        elif el.xpath('preceding::tok[1]'):

            prec_lem = el.xpath('preceding::tok[1]')[0].get('lemma')

        else:

            prec_lem = 'None'
```

With the valuable help of stackoverflow contributor Martin Honnen I managed to get through some problems but now I'm stuck with the following silly problem. When the first condition is met, what I get as a value is an element of a list which appears as ['DA0MS0'], whereas what I get when the second condition is met is just the string for value. I could get rid of the quotation marks using regex or in some other inelegant, brute force way but I would prefer to do this right.

If I do:

```
prec_lem = el.xpath('preceding::tok[1]/dtok[last()]).get('lemma')
```

I get the error message: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

I understand what the error message tells me but I don't understand why I'm getting a list element from one XPATH statement but not from the other. The internal structure of the  elements and that of the  elements is very similar. Why cannot I get the attribute values of these two elements in the same way?

After a lot of searches and consultation of the XPATH documentation I give up. I've seen mentions of string(), text() and I've tried those but nothing seems to work. I'm very new to this and there is obviously something very basic about XPATH I'm not understanding.

How does one get the value of the attribute without the quotation marks?

Comment: Why can't you use the same approach in both cases e.g. use `el.xpath('preceding::tok[1]/dtok[last()]')[0].get('lemma')` instead of `el.xpath('preceding::tok[1]/dtok[last()]/@lemma')`?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I had tried to use the same approach but it gave me an error. I think that I had forgotten about the index (i.e. [0]). Thank you for your patience but I still have a hard time figuring out how to use these indexes. I haven't found any tutorials or documentation where this is explained in a way I can understand. A [0] in a Python list is the first element and a [1] is the second element. But what are these [1] and [0] indicating here? What are these the first and second elements of? I am definitely confused about this syntax. I get the location paths but the rest ..

Comment: Well, part of that is just understanding the lxml `xpath` function, its documentation is at https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath and says "The return value types of XPath evaluations vary, depending on the XPath expression used [..] a list of items, when the XPath expression has a list as result. The items may include Elements (also comments and processing instructions), strings and tuples. Text nodes and attributes in the result are returned as 'smart' string values.". So that function gives you a Python list and the items in a Python list can be accessed by numbers starting with 0,1,2,3..

Comment: XPath has a similar syntax with positional predicates in the form of `[integerNumber]` e.g. `foo[1]` to select nodes (in XPath 1) in a node-set or (in XPath 2 and later) items in a sequence of items. In XPath the first index is 1, not 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me at this documentation. I had looked for info on this in the general documentation for XPath, not thinking that, of course, what I need is info on XPath as a function/method in lxml. I'll make sure I read this carefully.